# Garbage value getting logged in AWS logs using log4j2

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, gradle, logging, log4j2

My log4j2.xml file:

```
<Configuration status="debug">

<appenders>
    <Console name="LogToConsole">
        <PatternLayout disableAnsi="false" pattern="%style{%d{ISO8601}}{black} %highlight{%-5level }[%style{%t}{bright,blue}] %X{api-interaction-id} %style{%C{1.}}{bright,yellow} : %msg%n%throwable" />
    </Console>
    
    <RollingFile>
        <name>infoLogs</name>
        <fileName>/usr/${logPath}/info_log.log</fileName>
        <filePattern>/usr/${logPath}/$${date:yyyy-MM}/info-%d{MM-dd-yyyy}-%i.log.gz</filePattern>
        <PatternLayout pattern="%style{%d{ISO8601}}{black} %highlight{%-5level }[%style{%t}{bright,blue}] %X{api-interaction-id} %style{%c{1.}}{bright,yellow} : %msg%n%throwable" />
        <Policies>
            <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy/>
            <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="50MB" />
        </Policies>
        <ThresholdFilter level="INFO" onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="DENY" />
    </RollingFile>
</appenders>


<Loggers>
    <Logger name="com.demo" level="debug" additivity="false">
        
        <AppenderRef ref="infoLogs" level="debug"/>
        <AppenderRef ref="LogToConsole" level="debug" />
    </Logger>

    <Root level="debug">
        <AppenderRef ref="LogToConsole" level="debug" />
    </Root>
</Loggers>

</Configuration>
```

It is being logged properly in local location file like:

```
  2020-07-08T03:08:10,816 INFO  [main]  c.f.s.w.Application : Started Application in 131.144 seconds (JVM running for 141.392)
```

But in AWS log it is somehow with garbage values being added:

```
   [30m2020-07-09T06:55:16,979[m [32mINFO [m[[1;34mhttp-nio-8080-exec-6[m] [1;33mc.f.c.f.l.LoggerSlf4jImpl[m : Input Request Start:58b2d544-ca8a-45b0-9797-f5d4b79db0b8
```

Need solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you configure the output with things like `highlight` and `style`, Log4J will add ANSI escape sequences to the output. I assume the example in AWS is from CloudWatch, where the web console view does not support rendering ANSI styling.

There are a few browser plugins that will pick up the escape sequences and render them correctly. I haven't tried them, so I can't say how well they work.

Your other option, which I recommend, is to turn of ANSI coloring in the logs you ship to AWS. Even if you find a log viewer that supports ANSI, the presence of these escape sequences will make it difficult to analyse the logs (e.g. using CloudWatch Insights or Elasticsearch) should you want that in the future. If it is the console appender you use for AWS, set `disableAnsi` to `true`.